# How to dockerize apache php fpm for wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, fpm

Seems like this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEXBgQ71rvE) for basic Apache with php-fpm which I followed works fine.

I'm having some hard time on how I can build same using docker container running with basic wordpress, lots of tags seems to be confusing on which one to use. I already tried downloading docker images like **wordpress:6.3.1-php8.2-apache**  but still no idea on how to link it on a separate running container **wordpress:6.3.1-php8.2-fpm**